# Obter tamanho da fonte no HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou precisando de pegar as informações da fonte que é configurado na tag do HTML com o JQuery.

Eu sei que para pegar o tamanho do font-size é só utilizar:

css:

```
p {font-size: 12px;}
```

JS:

```
var tamanho = $("p").css('font-size');
```

A questão é, como posso pegar o tamanho da fonte que está configurado no HTML desta forma:

```
html {font: normal 16px / 25px 'Montserrat';}
```

Pensei em várias formas mas não consegui encontrar uma solução. É possível?

JQuery utilizado:
https://jsfiddle.net/wmosquini/eqs997h2/

Comment: Você quer pegar "literalmente": `16px / 25px` ou quer pegar o valor "compensado"?

Comment: Então, quero pegar apenas o 16px, que é o tamanho da fonte

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Equivalente ao do bfavaretto, mas com compatibilidade para navegadores antigos:

```js
function getStyle(elem, prop)
{
    if (elem.currentStyle) { //IE8
        prop = prop.replace(/-([a-z])/gi, function (value) {
            return value.toLowerCase();
        });
        
        return elem.currentStyle[prop];
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {//Navegadores modernos
        prop = prop.replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1').toLowerCase();
        
        return window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
    }
}

console.log(getStyle(document.getElementById('Teste'), 'font-size'));
console.log(getStyle(document.getElementById('Teste'), 'fontSize'));
```

```css
html {font: normal 16px / 25px 'Montserrat';}
```

```html
<p id="Teste">Foo bar</p>
```

---

### Extra

Mesmo usando jQuery.css ou getStyle existe um detalhe muito importante, **em diferentes navegadores** pode ocorrer de não retornar em pixels (`px`), pode retornar valores como `em` ou `pt`.

Para remover estes caracteres recomendo usar `.replace` com [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) e não usar `parseInt` sem checar se o valor é `null` ou outra coisa (como vazio), pois senão pode dar problema, faça assim:

```
tamanhoFonte = $(elemento).css('font-size'); //ou getStyle(elemento, 'font-size')
tamanhoFonte = tamanhoFonte.replace(/[a-z]/gi, ""); //Remove letras, mas mantem pontos e numeros
tamanhoFonte = tamanhoFonte ? parseInt(tamanhoFonte) : 0;
```

Comment: Então Guilherme, o Wictor passou, funcionou, mas apenas uma única execução, anexei o link do exemplo na pergunta, consegue identificar a questão? 
https://jsfiddle.net/wmosquini/eqs997h2/

Comment: @WendellMosquiniPozzatti estou olhando

Comment: Descobri, era problema no meu if... Removi e funcionou :)
Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @WendellMosquiniPozzatti está dando o erro: "JQuery is not defined", não tenho como testar.

Comment: Guilherme, engraçado, estou usando no chrome, funciona normalmente... Fui testar no Firefox e não funciona :|

Comment: Neste caso, teria que ser identificado o navegador e configurar a execução do JS de acordo com o navegador?

Comment: Essa é a ultima versão modificada e que está funcionando no chrome.
https://jsfiddle.net/wmosquini/eqs997h2/

Comment: Gulherme, fiz umas alterações e aparentemente agora está funcionando no Firefox, consegue testar? https://jsfiddle.net/eqs997h2/

Comment: @WendellMosquiniPozzatti editei a resposta, veja a parte que escrevi "extra"

Comment: Entendi Guilherme, muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda. :)

Comment: @WendellMosquiniPozzatti opa, que bom que deu certo!

Answer (score 7):

Com a função global [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```js
var elemento = document.getElementById('elemento'); // ou $('#elemento')[0]
var estilos = window.getComputedStyle(elemento, null);
var tamanho = estilos.getPropertyValue('font-size');

console.log(tamanho)
```

```css
html {font: normal 18px / 25px 'Montserrat';}
```

```html
<p id="elemento">
sfsadas fasda sdas dasd asdas da d 
</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Da mesma forma:

```
var tamanho = $("html").css('font-size');
```

E se quiser remover o "px" para trabalhar com o número inteiro:

```
var tamanho = parseInt(tamanho.replace("px",""));
```

Comment: É, com jQuery realmente esse é o caminho mais simples. Internamente, ele usa o `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: Wictor, funcionou perfeitamente :)